# How can I get the reflect constructor with Generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, constructor

now exists a class below:

```
class A{
    private A(HashMap map){

    }
}
```

how can I get the constructor that the parameters are generics with reflection?

EDIT : Question edited.

Comment: You haven't use templates or Generics here. Did you intend to leave Generics out of your example?

Comment: do you mean can you get generics info about the constructor? eg for private A(Map<K, V> map) find out about K and V?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have templates in Java. You can have Generics and you can get that information from the Constructor.

```
Constructor aConstructor = A.class.getConstructors()[0];
Class[] parameterTypes = aConstructor.getParameterTypes();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parameterTypes)); // prints [java.util.HashMap]
```

BTW: Is there any reason it has to be a HashMap and not a Map?

Comment: `getConstructors()` won't work here since it returns only `public` constructors. Based on the sample class A posted above, using `getDeclaredConstructors()` should sort things out.

Comment: @Sanjay, You are right. I had assumed a constructor is private for a good reason, i.e. you don't want to be able to access it from another class. A simpler approach would be to make `public` the constructors to be used by other classes.

Comment: @Sanjay @Peter thank you for help~ I mistook something recently. So what I want is all wrong.